# Error while loading kernel extension in Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, kernel

I am developing simple "hello world" kernel , successfully signed the code , there is no error in xcode.
while running below command

> sudo kextutil -v test.kext.

It shows the below output

> Defaulting to kernel file '/System/Library/Kernels/kernel'
>   Diagnostics for test.kext:
>   Code Signing Failure: code signature is invalid
>   test.kext appears to be loadable (not including linkage for on-disk libraries).
>   ERROR: invalid signature for com.osxkernel.test, will not load.

It is saying that invalid signature but I am not getting any error in xcode regarding signing.
What will be the possible solution for this?